# Why is there a red line splitting my terminal window into two parts when I open python files?

Tags: neovim

As you see in the picture, this is the line I mean.

[image: None]

First off, I'm using Neovim. This line only appears when I try to edit python files. Everything is fine with any other language. I think it's because of Syntastic. If I recall correctly, Syntastic sets a maximum length for each line that is 79 characters. This red line delimits the 79th character. When any character exceeds this line, the `This line is too long` warning appears.

I tried to edit the maximum line length using this command

```
let g:syntastic_python_pylint_post_args="--max-line-length=200"
```

I also tried to turn Syntastic off for python files but the line is still there even when Syntastic is not working. [This is my init.vim file](https://pastebin.com/z2bW5DrE). It's generated by vim bootstrap but I added some edits to it.

How to get rid of this red line? Thanks in advance

Comment: `:verbose set colorcolumn? `

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt it works, Thank you. `set cc=` . You pointed me to something I didn't know which is `colorcolumn`. After knowing it I managed to find the line that sets it and I turned it off. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this line to your vimrc:

```
set colorcolumn=0
```

If you want colorcolumn to remain but with different color, then add

```
set colorcolumn=81 " or something you want
hi ColorColumn cterm=none gui=none guibg=white ctermfg=white " or whatever you like
```